# how to send ajax request to laravel controller public function

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have page that load data from laravel controller,
there is a button to call jquery function,

and there is a phone number in the button value, so I need send sms that number,

here I attached code that I use,

SMS gateway fully functional, I remove personal data for security resons,

link

```
<i><a class="btn btn-info" id="Confirm2" value="{{$padd->ContactNum02}}">Confirm</a></i>
```

JQ code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#Confirm2").click(function(){
    $("#ConfirmNo02input").show();
    $("#Confirm2").hide();

    OTPSend();
    var PhoneNum = $("#Confirm2").val();
    function OTPSend( PhoneNum) {
            
        $.ajax({
        url: 'OTP_send',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype:'json',
        data:{SearchKey:PhoneNum},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("run")
                console.log("run");
            })    
            .fail(function() {
                alert("fail")
                console.log("error");
            })
                }
    });
});
</script>
```

route

```
Route::post('/OTP_send', 'ServicesController@OTP' )->name('OTP_send');
```

controller file

```
   public function OTP(Services $services)
    {
         
        $testNum='0753505625';
        $api_instance = new SmsApi();
        $user_id = "xxxxx";
        $api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $message = "test SMS";
        $PhoneNo=ltrim( $testNum , "0");
        $to ="94".$PhoneNo;
        $sender_id = "NotifyDEMO";
        try {
            $api_instance->sendSMS($user_id, $api_key, $message, $to, $sender_id);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception when calling SmsApi->sendSMS: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            } 
        return response()->json(['message' => 'successfull'],200);*/

    }
```

this code is not working, can you help me

Comment: "_this code is not working_" What does that mean? Does it not send anything? Does it not receive data? Sends SMS to the wrong number? Server error? Might also be better to use a `<button type="button"...>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: see the  oonsole .There u can see the error

Comment: Your `function OTPSend( PhoneNum) {` takes a `PhoneNum` parameter, you use it without: `OTPSend();`

Comment: You should call OTP function with passing the value ``OTPSend(PhoneNum);``

Comment: 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ VM856 jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ VM856 jquery.min.js:2
OTPSend @ 10:234
(anonymous) @ 10:230
dispatch @ VM856 jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ VM856 jquery.min.js:2

Comment: @sameera check the answer below and let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code.
First change your HTML like this, You need a button not a link.

```
<i><button class="btn btn-info" id="Confirm2" value="{{$padd->ContactNum02}}">Confirm</button></i>
```

Change your Javascript to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#Confirm2',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ConfirmNo02input").show();
    $("#Confirm2").hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'OTP_send', // URL for the function
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            phone:$("#Confirm2").val()
        },
        success:function(result){
            if(result.status == 'success'){
                alert('ran');
            }
            else{
                alert('failure');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And finally change your controller to this.

```
public function OTP(Request $request){
    $testNum='0753505625';
    // use this to send the text on number coming from the button
    // $testNum = $request->phone; 
    $api_instance = new SmsApi();
    $user_id = "xxxxx";
    $api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $message = "test SMS";
    $PhoneNo=ltrim( $testNum , "0");
    $to ="94".$PhoneNo;
    $sender_id = "NotifyDEMO";
    try{
        $api_instance->sendSMS($user_id, $api_key, $message, $to, $sender_id);
        $response['status'] = 'success';
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling SmsApi->sendSMS: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    } 
    return $response;
}
```

And finally, make sure that your route which you have passed in ajax is correctly pointing to this function of controller.

Comment: @sameera did you added the above line in your controller ?

Comment: @sameera Okay. Is there any line like use requestContent ? in you controller in use section

Comment: there is not like this , even word "requestContent"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217433/discussion-between-khalid-khan-and-sameera).

Comment: POST http://sewa.test/OpenMyServiceAdd/OpenMyServiceAdd/OTP_send 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ 10:229
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2